# Grails Security Plugin Issue

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have created the following Controller

```
@Secured(["IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"])
class HomeController {    
    def index() {}
}
```

In UrlMappings.groovy

```
"/"(controller: 'home', action: 'index')
```

I integrated a nice UI theme files in assets folder. So far so good index page is working fine for valid credentials. but if I make the controller

```
@Secured(["IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"])
class HomeController { 
    def index() {}
}
```

then it is showing up blank page. It is supposed to show index page with integrated theme. What went wrong. Do I need to do extra configuration to allow Anonymous users.
I use
Grails 3.2.9
Groovy 2.4.10

Comment: add /home/index or /home/** to your static rules in application.groovy where u have all your images css defined with permitAll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. Interceptor is the culprit here. I didn't return true at the end of the interceptor assuming it returns, as it is used to do with Filters in grails2.x. Since it is my first application in grails3.x I got confused. Thank you All
It is my earlier code

```
class CrtInterceptor {

    def springSecurityService

    CrtInterceptor() {
        matchAll().excludes(controller: 'login|logout')
    }

    boolean before() {  some code }
    some code
}
```

No I changed it to

```
boolean before() {
      // some code
     return true
}
```

Now, its working like a charm